# Cannot find SearchResults.cs template for Sitefinity 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, sitefinity

I've been working on a site built in Telerik Sitefinity 7, and need to customize the SearchResults widget so that I can filter the pages it chooses to display for different parts of the site. I understand to do this I need to create a custom widget, but I am having a hard time finding the default SearchResults code behind file to template it off of. Does anyone know where I can find this, and possibly what methods I need to override to accomplish such a task (I know Search is one of them, but without being able to implement over the interface in VS I am lost to their names or functions)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this applies to Sitefinity 7.0, but hopefully this may help a little: http://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-customize-search-results-by-overriding-the-searchresults-class

It looks like you would need to override the SearchResults class (I think it's found in Telerik.Sitefinity.Services.Search.Web.UI.Public) and then also implement the ISearchResultsBuilder interface to actually return the search results that you want. I was able to use the Object Browser to view the methods that are in the base SearchResults class (but obviously not the implementation details of them).

There used to be an SDK, but they've discontinued it and from a quick look in my 6.0 SDK, it didn't include the code behind file for the SearchResults widget.

Comment: I've tried to use the code on that page, but I can't seem to find the namespace for ISearchResultsViewer. And the implementation on their end is truely the mystery haha.

Comment: Ah, sorry :/ In my 7.3 Sitefinity instance, the GetSearcher() method actually returns an ISearcher object (not an ISearchResultsBuilder, maybe that's an 8.0 thing). ISearcher is an interface within the SearchResults class. But still, unfortunately no implementation details. You may be able to get the code-behind if you post on their forums (haven't had any experience with that myself)

Answer (score 0):

The last override that was done on the search widget we used:

```
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Services;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Services.Search;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Services.Search.Configuration;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Services.Search.Data;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Services.Search.Web.UI.Public;
```

This override started in 7.0 and now is running in 8.

Also i might suggest using JustDecompile its open and running on my machine everyday to look through sitefnity dlls